# Всплывающий калькулятор на JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Всем привет!
Нужен сабж, в простом <input type=text>
Пример с календарем: http://s2.ipicture.ru/uploads/20131112/xuI3Eo2X.jpg
Возможно что бы вместо календаря простенький калькулятор выскакивал?
Есть ссылочка у кого на подобное? Не ищется что то...
Спасибо!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://keith-wood.name/calculator.html

Comment: От спасибо!!